# Does rotate(X/Y/Z) CSS3 transforms change the direction of axes vectors of the element under transform?

Tags: css, css-transforms

What I know is rotate(X/Y/Z) transforms rotate the element along 50% (X) 50% (Y) 0px (Z) by default; which means for a flat rectangular shape it will rotate exactly along it's center.

If the above understanding is correct, does the rotation of an element along some axis (say, rotateX for now) also change the direction of the remaining two axes (Y and Z, in this case) ?

Being said that, if I apply a rotateX (-45deg) transform first - on a rectangle, after which I want to translate it in Z i.e. translateZ ('x'px) - where 'x' is positive integer, should I be expecting it to come towards me (which will be the case without applying rotateX (-45deg) transform) or should be translating in a direction of 45deg to the right of me ?

Comment: You could answer this yourself in seconds by trying it.

Comment: I did try and it seemed to me this way (i.e. the directions do change). But, being new to CSS, I wanted to be completely sure before going ahead, because I'm not even sure (as of now), in what order are multiple transforms working. Hence, first thought of getting this cleared by the community.